# At any point we need to tell the top k products based on quantity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashmap, heap

There is a stream of data coming.
Data contains Product Id and Quantity.
At any point we need to tell the top k products based on quantity.

My Approach :

Maintain one minHeap of size k
Maintain one hashmap which stores Product id as key and Product quantity,Heap index as Value.

Now one data is received , check whether product id is present in hashmap or not.

If present in hashmap :

Update the product quantity in heap(As product quantity will be increased).
Update the new quantity,new index in hashmap

If not present in hashmap :

Check whether new product quantity is greater than min value in heap or not
If it is greater then remove the root of heap and replace with new value.

Problem :
The problem with my approach is that product ids can be repeated at any time due to which product quantity will increased.
What approach should I use so that I can store both product quantity and heap index , because some products at present might not be in heap but in future they can be part of heap.

Comment: If the quantity field in the data that you receive is the current total quantity of that product then I would stick with your scheme. If you receive an additional quantity everytime to be added on top of the previously received figure then it's a matter to think. In both scenarios I would use the `productID` as the map key.

Comment: Additional quantity is received every time a productID is repeated.
I was thinking of using TRIE and in trieNode i can include product quantity and heapIndex(-1 if not present in the heap).

Comment: One way of handling this is based on probability. So if at any given point of time, you need to find top 100 elements, maintain the heap for top 10K elements. So if your data distribution is good i.e. the stream does not have too many spurts, you shall be right about your top 100 numbers with a high probability. Ofcourse, the product quantity number will be not be exact for a lot of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough memory to store all of the products and their counts, then maintain a hash map keyed by product id, as well as a tree structure ([AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree), for example) that's ordered by frequency.

When an update comes in:

- If the product is not in the hash map, add it to the hash map and add it to the tree with a frequency of 1.
- If the product is already in the hash map, look it up in the tree, increase its frequency, and adjust the node's position in the tree.

Adding a node to the tree and adjusting a node's position are O(log n) operations.

When you have to get the top 'k' products by frequency, you can use an inorder traversal of the tree, with an early out when you reach `k`.

If you don't have the memory to store counts for every product, things get a little tricky and you'll probably have to go with approximation algorithms. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19802/top-k-frequent-items-in-data-stream gives some ideas about that.